# UDP write to socket and read from socket at the same time(again with modification)

Tags: php, sockets, udp

Server:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

socket_bind($socket, '192.168.1.7', 11104);

$from = "";
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);
//$buf=socket_read($socket, 2048);

echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
$msg="Sikerult";

//socket_write($socket, $msg, strlen($msg));
socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, '192.168.1.6', 11105);
//socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Client:

```
<?php
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
$result = socket_connect($sock, '192.168.1.6', 11105);
$msg = "Sikerult";
$len = strlen($msg);
//socket_write($sock, $msg, strlen($msg));
socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, '192.168.1.7', 11104);
//$buf=socket_read($sock, 2048);
socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);
echo $buf;
socket_close($sock);
?>
```

The server receives the data from the client but the client got nothing from the server and not stop running.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a UDP socket then why do you need to connect in the first place. Doesn't this suffice?

```
<?php
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

    $msg = "Sikerult";
    $len = strlen($msg);

    socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, '192.168.1.7', 11104);

    socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 12, 0, '192.168.1.7', 11104);
    echo $buf;

    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `192.168.1.7:11104` is your server.

In server you need to send packet back to where you've received it from:

```
//...
$msg="Sikerult";
//...
socket_sendto($socket, $msg, strlen($msg), 0, $from, $port);
```

In the client you're connecting to itself. You should connect it to server:

```
$srvIP = '192.168.1.7';
$srvPort = 11104;
$result = socket_connect($sock, $srvIP, $srvPort);
$msg = "Sikerult";
$len = strlen($msg);
socket_send($sock, $msg, $len, 0);
socket_recv($sock, $buf, 12, 0);
```

Comment: to socket_recvfrom you can't insert $srvIP and $srvPort, you get that from you get the data