# What's the advantage of throwing an exception?

Tags: php, exception

```
function foo() {
    // Some code.
    throw new Exception('Ouch'); // Why don't I just output "Ouch" here?
    // Code continued.
}

function bar() {
    try {
        foo()
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); // Ouch
    }
}
```

The code above demonstrates a basic use of the `Exception` class in PHP. What's the advantage of throwing an exception? I mean, what's the advantage of *deferring* the problem and not dealing with it immediately inside `foo()`?

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309882/exceptions-in-php-why-nobody-uses-them) don't address this question.

Comment: And you will check every possible errors, right?

Comment: as you said yourself, it defers the problem. It is useful when you can't/won't deal with it immediately.

Comment: Makes the code easier to read - deal with everything working at the top and deal with the problems at the bottom of page

Comment: Also, you often do not actually throw the exception yourself, the code that you're attempting to execute does.  So if you put that code inside a try/catch block, you can gracefully handle those unexpected cases (always expect the unexpected).  Maybe if there's an exception in a certain section of code, you want to log that to a specific file, email a specific person, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exceptions in php... why nobody uses them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309882/exceptions-in-php-why-nobody-uses-them)

Comment: @trincot the answers to that question aren't really relevant if you read them. They address the question of why exceptions aren't used much in PHP (quite different to what I'm asking here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `function foo()`, you don't necessarily know that the developer who will be calling it (who might just be Future You) has thought of everything. So if they, for example, forgot to validate user input and tried to call `myAwesomeDivisionFunction(3,0)`, your awesome division function would throw some kind of `Exception` (possibly a `DivideByZeroException extends RangeException`). This would stop the code there, and the developer would be forced to fix it.

While you could just do `echo "Divide by zero error";`, what logical step would you take next? There isn't one. You can't assume anything any more, and so you throw the Exception.

Comment: So you're saying it's better to give the developer who calls `foo()` the freedom to handle the problem instead of "hard-coding" a solution myself (like echoing inside `foo()`)?

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise, let's say the person calling `foo()` is aware there may be an error, but they want to `try {}` it anyway. Instead of the simple `try..catch` stuff, they'd have to `ob_start();`, run the function, check `ob_get_contents()` maybe, call `ob_end_clean()`... it's a mess.

Comment: Thanks, you've been a lot of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```
function parseInt($string) {
    // Return the int represented by this string
    // If the string does not represent an int, throw an exception
}
```

Now imagine that `$string == "foo"`. What does your function return? It can't return an int, because that would not make any sense. It can't return something that is not an int, because it would surely break something (consider this call `$score = parseInt("foo") + parseInt("42")`).

That's where an Exception is useful. It breaks in a predictable way, and avoid leaving you in an unknown state.

Comment: I don't quite follow your example. Where are you throwing the exception?

Comment: @henrywright the parseInt function would throw an exception if it was unable to parse the string.